# Slow SQL Queries after listing larger table

Tags: mysql, sql, database, performance, innodb

Lets call the database in question `db` and lets also call the smaller table with a few hundred rows `x` and the larger with above 10k rows `y`.

---

When I issue a query to table `x`, the query is issued without any problems in about **0.0003** seconds using the basic query `SELECT * FROM x LIMIT 25`.

[image]

This applies to all smaller tables in `db` with all queries taking about 0,3ms to process.

However, after issuing the same basic query `SELECT * FROM y LIMIT 25` to table `y` the process is significantly slower. Sometimes taking up **100ms** to process.

[image: Snip]

---

It effects the query time for table `y` **and** the query time for table `x`.

[image: Snip]

---

The problem seems to go away after either re-issuing the listing of table `x` a few times or listing another small table in `db`. A table from another database will still be slow.

I've read a lot about optimization and performance enhancements that can be made to increase query speeds. None of them seem to cover this issue however.

Comment: Bot tables fields are the same? Do they have FK? Can you give us the description of them, maybe with that we can help you in a better way.

Comment: I think you should think Caching

Comment: @VíctorLópez It doesn't seem to matter how the tables are structured. I have another large table in another db with fewer columns, still get the issue. And they're not FK constrained

Comment: @RiggsFolly I have the PK of both tables indexed

Comment: I hope you do not have a redundant `INDEX(pk)`.  Keep in mind that `PRIMARY KEY(pk)` is both `UNIQUE` and `INDEX`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Optimization and Performance and table size are not the issues; caching is.

- Since there is no `WHERE`, `GROUP BY`, nor `ORDER BY`, indexing does not matter.
- `LIMIT 25`, without `ORDER BY`, will grab the first 25 rows; it does not matter how many rows there are after those.
- If the "Query cache" in on, then the *first* time you run a query, it will be slower.  After that (until bumped out of cache), it will be "fast" -- 0.3ms is pretty typical.
- Even if the QC is off, there are other caches involved that could explain the difference.

Comment: Yeah, the slowness happens every time I run the query and it seems to also affects all queries run after it no matter which one

Comment: `innodb_buffer_pool_size` is the important caching tunable.  What is its value?  How much RAM do you have?

Comment: `innodb_buffer_pool_size` was set to the default 16M. I changed its value and sure enough, things appear to run faster. Thanks!

Comment: Good.  If you have at least 8GB, 70% of RAM is a good setting for that.  If 16M is the default, you must have an "old" copy of MySQL.